# Python deleting line or replacing line with null for a line in dictionary

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python. I have 2 dictionaries : `group1` and `group2` and I need to replace the line will null/delete for line in text file if in dictionary:

```
{'car': set(['ab', 'ef', 'ad', 'cd']), 'bike': set(['ac', 'de'])}
{'car': ['go', 'drive', 'enjoy'], 'bike': ['ride']}
```

My file:

```
  !hello!!
mycar
car(ab,ef,ad,cd)
 go
 drive
 enjoy

bike(ac,de)
    ride
```

Expected output

```
  !hello!!
mycar
```

The output has to be written to the same file without affecting/other lines and its indentations!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'written to the same file'? do you mean overwriting it? appending to it? you can't just 'edit' a file, like you might in an editor like notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import re

path = 'your file path'

group1 = {'car': set(['ab', 'ef', 'ad', 'cd']), 'bike': set(['ac', 'de'])}
group2 = {'car': ['go', 'drive', 'enjoy'], 'bike': ['ride']}


f = open(path, 'r')

text = f.readlines()
f.close()
flag = 0
lines = []
for line in text:
    for i in list(group1['car']):
        if re.search(i, line):
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 1:
        flag = 0
        continue
    for i in list(group1['bike']):
        if re.search(i, line):
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 1:
        flag = 0
        continue        
    for i in group2['car']:
        if re.search(i, line):
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 1:
        flag = 0
        continue        
    for i in group2['bike']:
        if re.search(i, line):
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 1:
        flag = 0
        continue        
    lines.append(line)

f = open(path, 'w')
for l in lines:
    f.write(l)
f.close()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers